# Can't seem to repeat my low-high game

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a simple high low game that asks the user after playing if they would like to play again. If I remove the outer while loop the logic of the inner loop does exactly what I want it to do, however I am unsure how to wrap the inner loop with an outer loop that will ask the play again question and if the answer is yes put them back into the inner loop. Below is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLoGuess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); // Creates scanner object.
        Random numb = new Random();             // Creates an instance of the random class.
        int guess = -1;                         // Placeholder for users guess.
        int answer = numb.nextInt(100)+1;       // Generates a random number for the game.
        int count = 0;                          // Placeholder for the guess counter.
        int sentinel = 0;                       // Placeholder for players answer as to whether they want to play again or not.
        String newgame = "y";

        while (newgame.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            while (guess != sentinel && guess != answer)                //Loop that ends when user enters a zero.
            {
                System.out.println ("Enter a number between 1-100 or 0 to quit");
                guess = scan.nextInt();
                count++;

                if (guess < answer && guess > 0 )
                {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low, guess again");
                }
                else if (guess > answer)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Your guess is to high, guess again");
                }

                else if (guess == answer)
                {
                    System.out.println ();
                    System.out.println ("You guessed correctly, you win!!!");
                    System.out.println ("It took you " + count + " guesses");
                }
            }
            System.out.print();
            System.out.println("Play another game: y or n?");
            newgame = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put these initializations into the outer loop:

```
int guess = -1;
int answer = numb.nextInt(100)+1;
int count = 0;
```

Otherwise they keep the value from the last game and the inner loop will not be executed any more.

Comment: By putting the variables inside the outer loop and deleting the last system.out.print(); the game worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you never reset your guess, sentinel, or answer variables

so (guess != sentinel && guess != answer) always evaluates to false after the first time the game is played, and therefore the inner while loop never executes after the first game

```
 while (guess != sentinel && guess != answer) //this is false after the first game because you don't reset variables
            { ...}
```

***Update for OP comment:***
to get your code to do what you want you need to add the resets between the outter and inner while loop like this

```
           while (newgame.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            {
            guess = -1;                  
            answer = numb.nextInt(100)+1;
            count = 0;
            while (guess != sentinel && guess != answer)                //Loop that ends when user enters a zero.
                { ...}
}
```

Comment: Sorry but how do I reset the variables? I am new to programming and am unsure.

Comment: no problem remember to select and accept (the one) and up vote (all) answer(s) you found useful.

Answer (score -1):

Replace newgame = scan.nextLine(); by this : newgame = scan.next();

And you need to initialise your variables inside your while loop, so that the flag is reseted to false and the random generate new result to guess.

```
    public class Game

{

 public static void main(String[] args)

 {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Creates scanner object.
Random numb = new Random(); // Creates an instance of the random class.

String newgame = "y";

while (newgame.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
  int count = 0; // Placeholder for the guess counter.
  int guess = -1; // Placeholder for users guess.
  int answer = numb.nextInt(100) + 1; // Generates a random number for the game.
  int sentinel = 0; // Placeholder for players answer as to whether they want to play again or not.

  while (guess != sentinel && guess != answer) // Loop that ends when user enters a zero.
  {
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-100 or 0 to quit");
    guess = scan.nextInt();
    count++;

    if (guess < answer && guess > 0) {
      System.out.println("Your guess is too low, guess again");
    } else if (guess > answer) {
      System.out.println("Your guess is to high, guess again");
    }

    else if (guess == answer) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("You guessed correctly, you win!!!");
      System.out.println("It took you " + count + " guesses");
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Play another game: y or n?");
  newgame = scan.next();
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is the solution. Care to explain why?

Comment: nextLine only return the line that was skipped, while next gives you the next token

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain why that happens, please?